# Percentual to check for loop in goroutines until it's not finished?

Tags: go, goroutine

everyone. I would like to check the status of my routines by starting a loop and displaying the results in an HTTP response. Can someone help me with this? I'm thinking of something like this:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func task(registers string[], status <-chan int) {
   for index, register := range registers {
      fmt.Printf("Status processing %d/%d", index,len(registers))
      status <- index
  }
}

func main() {
   status := make(chan int, 4)   

   http.HandleFunc("/process", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        registers := [16]int{1,6,56,10,50,60,10,5,9,8,10,25,56,10,20,365}
        partial := 4

        for i:=0; i<4;i++ {
           if i == 0 {
              go task(registers[i:partial], status)
           } else {
              go task(registers[(partial*i)+1:partial*(i+1)], status)
           }
           
        }
        count:= 0
        for len(status) > 0 && <-status > 0 {
           count += <-status
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Processed loop status: %d/16", count)
    })
   fmt.Println("Server is running")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
   }

}
```

But, for some reason, doing it this way can potentially cause a deadlock because when I execute it, it never returns a value after the first iteration. Can someone help me?

Comment: `<-status > 0` receives a value from the channel and checks if it's greater than 0. Doing this removes that value from the channel so `count += <-status` may block (and you are ignoring every second value). You are also assuming that values are being added to `status` faster than you are removing them (when I run this in the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iQwJzcKLuJr) it exits immediately without processing anything). So you have created a race which will have unpredictable behaviour. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71024471/11810946) for some options.

Comment: So, in this case, would putting the counter to iterate in a goroutine solve my problem?

Comment: IT WORKS thank you very much

Comment: No worries - just bear in mind that if multiple requests are being processed simultaneously the results might not be what you expect (because you will end up with multiple goroutines reading from `status` concurrently).